# JQuery UI loading another MVC view in modal breaks css

Tags: jquery, css

I an using this upload code from GitHub in my project:https://github.com/blackcity/Backload
I want to open this upload view in a modal dialog box from another view. This works fine except the css from the upload page breaks the styles on the main view even after the modal is closed.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#upload').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizeable: false,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        width: 700,
        open: function () {
            $(this).load('/upload/');
        }
    });
});
```

View

```
<div id="dialog">dialog here</div><div id='upload'>Upload picture</div>
```

I haven't worked with a modal dialog before so maybe there an conventional way to prevent the styles from remaining on the main view. Maybe something can be added to the close function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file upload project I downloaded from the link above is using bootstrap styles which were breaking the styles on my view when the upload view dialog opened. I eventually removed some styles from the bootstrap.debug.css which were overwriting my styles.